# Is '<<<' a rotation operator in verilog?

Tags: verilog

whether <<< 1 will do a left circular rotation by 1 bit. I want to know whether this operator exists?? Whether it will do a left circular rotation by 1 bit or I have to use concatenation for this.

Comment: This question should be easily answerable by reading the latest language reference manual

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No `<<<` is an arithmetic left shift operator which pads 0 at the right while keeping the sign if it is signed. But rather `<<` is a logical left shift which does the same but will not consider the sign.

Yes, you need to use concatenation.

The easiest way would be

```
wire [7:0] in;
wire [7:0] out;

assign out = {in[6:0], in[7]};
```

Ref http://vlsi.pro/verilog-operators/#shift